# Spring MVC security not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring mvc, I have tried to follow a security example illustrated in http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration

I have completed all the steps but nothing happened rather than usual execution without security settings. the tutorial claims that a login page will be displayed first. but that didn't happen. I accessed the system as there isn't any security constraints.

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters, the 
        root application context is created by it -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.channelit.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your security control code?

Comment: I have edited my entry to include the java class i use to security configuration. I am new to Spring so forgive me if i didn't know what to include in the question

Comment: this link is absolutely nice Spring Security Starter - http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/

Comment: okay i posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You miss restrict url in SecurityConfig class.

Add this code snippet to your SecurityConfig class as below:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()          
        .antMatchers("/your_restrict_url_here/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .and().formLogin();

    }
```

You can refer more details [here.](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)